# Link.innertext for multiple option VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I reach a website with below code and click a link however I recognised that for different sitiuation word can be 2 type.
first one is in use in code "fener" the second one is "buyuk fener". I need to click that link which is in use.

so i cant find anything to solve it

```
Dim link As Object
Set doc = ie.document
For Each link In doc.Links
If link.innerText = Sheets("Mail").Range("A15").Text Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next link
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
For Each link In doc.Links
If link.innerText = "Fener" Then
link.Click
Exit For
End If
Next link
```

Comment: check `instr` and use to check if the link **contains** `buyuk fener`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks for your comment. I did not use instr before. can you please be more specific? thanks

Comment: [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) will allow you to check if a string contains a specific text, returning a number if found. If not found, it will return 0. With this, you could check if the link contains the word `fener` and click on it if needed.